# Rounding 0.5 to 1 and not to 0 in R

Tags: r

When doing rounding in R using the Round function:

round(0.5) and round(2.5), generate (0 and 2); well as I need my output file to be (1 and 3); is there any other simple function like "Round" that can do the job as listed above in R ?

Comment: use `ceiling()`.. Read More.. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/ceil

Comment: ceiling(4.4) generates 5 well as I need to generate 4 instead; I am sorry but it doesn't work